# Solana Determine Date and Time of Inflation Reward Distribution by Epoch

Tags: python, json, json-rpc, solana

Is there any way to determine the exact date and time that corresponds to when inflation rewards were distributed for a given epoch? For example, the following:

```
payload = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getInflationReward",
    "params": [
      [my_staking_address], {"epoch": epoch}
    ]
  }
```

returns:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': [{'amount': 15711280, 'commission': 0, 'effectiveSlot': 103680000, 'epoch': 239, 'postBalance': 4799957221}], 'id': 1}
```

but there is no date and time associated with when the inflation reward was distributed. I need this information for tax purposes since I need to determine the price of SOL at the time the staking reward was received.

Given only the epoch, how can I determine the exact date and time of when the staking reward was received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `effectiveSlot` from that return is going to help you more, since you can use that with `getBlockTime` to get the timestamp for when that slot was processed: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblocktime

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.